# Django API ManyToMany on existing databse not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

at the moment I try to get recipes from my API. I have a Database with two tables one is with recipes and their ids but without the ingredients, the other table contains the ingredients and also the recipe id. Now I cant find a way that the API "combines" those. Maybe its because I added in my ingredient model to the  recipe id the related name, but I had to do this because otherwise, this error occurred:

```
ERRORS:
recipes.Ingredients.recipeid: (fields.E303) Reverse query name for 'Ingredients.recipeid' clashes with field name 'Recipe.ingredients'.
        HINT: Rename field 'Recipe.ingredients', or add/change a related_name argument to the definition for field 'Ingredients.recipeid'.
```

### Models

```
from django.db import models

class Ingredients(models.Model):
    ingredientid = models.AutoField(db_column='IngredientID', primary_key=True, blank=True)
    recipeid = models.ForeignKey('Recipe', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='recipeid', blank=True, null=True, related_name='+')
    amount = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=100)
    unit = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=100)
    unit2 = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=100)
    ingredient = models.CharField(db_column='Ingredient', blank=True, null=True, max_length=255)
    
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Ingredients'  

class Recipe(models.Model):
    recipeid = models.AutoField(db_column='RecipeID', primary_key=True, blank=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    title = models.CharField(db_column='Title', blank=True, null=True, max_length=255)  # Field name made lowercase.
    preperation = models.TextField(db_column='Preperation', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    images = models.CharField(db_column='Images', blank=True, null=True, max_length=255)  # Field name made lowercase.
    #ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredients) 
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredients, related_name='recipes')
    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'Recipes'
```

When there is no issue it has to be in the serializer or in the view.

### Serializer

```
class IngredientsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   # ingredients = serializers.CharField(source='ingredients__ingredients')

    class Meta:
        model = Ingredients
        fields = ['ingredient','recipeid']

class FullRecipeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    ingredients = IngredientsSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = ['title','ingredients']
```

### View

```
class FullRecipesView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = FullRecipeSerializer
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.AllowAny
    ]
    queryset = Recipe.objects.all()
```

[This is at the moment my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Kalo.jpg)
But I want e.g. the recipe with id 0 and all the ingredients which have also recipe id 0.
I really hope that you can help me. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Rename `ingredients` to some other name in `FullRecipeSerializer`. It conflicts with `ingredients` in `Recipe` model. This should solve your issue. For example

```
class FullRecipeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    ingredients_recipe = IngredientsSerializer(many=True, source= 'ingredientid')

    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = ['title','ingredients_recipe']
```

Comment: You mean both? One in fields and the other ingredients variable?

Comment: Then this error comes up: "Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `ingredients_recipe` on serializer `FullRecipeSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Recipe` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Recipe' object has no attribute 'ingredients_recipe'."

Comment: add source to `ingredients_recipe`

Comment: Now it comes 'int' object is not iterable maybe because recipe id is an int?

Comment: The int issue was the many=True but what I now get is https://imgur.com/a/9vaoqRu

Comment: Yes thats what I did but now everything is null